# Best way to save flask session as a file

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm building a data analysis flask application and I want to allow the user to save the `session` object as a file on their local file system (in case their session expires after 31 days). What's the best way to do this?

I've looked into pickling the `session` object but it doesn't look like the pickle can be sent to the user's computer (`pickle.dump` simply saves the pickle to the computer hosting the application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is a dictionary. Add an endpoint that dumps the session to JSON, and serves it as a file download.

```
@app.route('/download_session')
def download_session():
    r = jsonify(dict(session))
    r.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='session.json')
    return r
```

This doesn't seem like a very good idea though. If you're putting enough data in the session that the user would care to look at it, you're putting too much in the session. Also, the session can contain data that's relevant to the web app but not useful to the user. Instead, you probably want to write an endpoint that serves just the data the user needs.